# Как округлить края элементу?

Tags: android-view, android, activity, view

**Имеется:**
[image]

**Хочется:**
[image]

**Вопрос:** как?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

следует создать ресурс

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:shape="rectangle">
      <solid
        android:color="#FF9DA1"/>

      <corners
        android:radius="15dp" />
       </shape>
```

у этого элемента  задать фоном созданный ресурс

Comment: Оч. круто - решпект

Comment: А зачем общим то делать?

Comment: Да, незачем, вернул авторское